# How to change users role based on json file listed value with discord bot

Tags: json, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot which has a level system for users to level up, they can check their level and get exp from each message sent which is stored in a json file. I would like to add a function to this code which changes a users role at a particular level. I understand I need to have an if statement involving the lvl_end variable however i'm not quite sure how this code should look. Here's my code, i'd really appreciate some help with this.

```
import discord
import json
import asyncio
import os
import time
import random
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online and ready to connect to server")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='SHADOWSMAR is cool!'))


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    messages = []
    async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount)):
        messages.append(message)
    await client.delete_messages(messages)
    await client.say('Messages deleted')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Tourist')
    await client.add_roles(member, role)

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    upgrade = random.randint(5,10)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, upgrade)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

#Update data
async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1
#Get xp per message
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp
#Level up
async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** 1.75)


    if lvl_start < lvl_end and lvl_end == 5 or lvl_end == 10 or lvl_end == 15 or lvl_end == 20:
        await client.send_message(channel, '{} has leveld up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))

    users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

#Rank check
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rank(ctx, user : discord.Member=None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.message.author
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f) 
        lvl_end = users[user.id]['level']
        exp = users[user.id]['experience']
        rank = discord.Embed(name="{}'s rank is".format(user.name), colour = 0xec134b)
        rank.add_field(name="{}'s rank:".format(user.name), value="{}".format(lvl_end))
        rank.add_field(name="total experience points:", value="{}".format(exp), inline=True)
        rank.add_field(name="Highest role", value=user.top_role)
        rank.set_footer(text="Thanks for being part of the community :D")
        rank.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        await client.say(embed=rank)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a dictionary set up where the users level would correspond to their rank and check for that rank every time they write a message
For example something like this:

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  user = message.author
  role_dict = {1:"role#1_name",2:"role#2_name",3:"role#3_name"}
  roles = message.server.roles
  try:
    for key,value in role_dict.items():
      if value in [rl.name for rl in user.roles]:
        await client.remove_roles(user,get(roles,name = value))
  except discord.Forbidden:
    print("Bot permissions aren't high enough to remove roles from this user")


  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)

  await client.add_roles(user,get(roles,name = role_dict[users[user.id]['level']]))
```